# Evaluate an integral of a region

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $R$ be the finite region in the positive quadrant bounded by the
> hyperbolas $xy = 1$, $xy = 4$, $xy^2 = 1$ and $xy^2 = 5$.
> Evaluate
>
> $$\int_Rx^4y^7\, dx\,dy.$$

Would this become a standard double integral question, once the limits have been determined? How would I determine the limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a change of variables will be more convenient here.

Let $u=xy$, $v=xy^2$, then $1\leq u\leq 4$, $1\leq v\leq5$ and $x^4y^7=uv^3$. Since 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=2xy^2-xy^2=xy^2=v,$$
we can convert this integral into 
$$\int_1^4\int_1^5uv^3\cdot\frac1v\,dv\,du.$$